# load php file on folder assets in android studio

Tags: php, android, android-studio, android-assets

I'm building an offline Android expert system app, and can android studio read php files from the assets folder? If yes, please help me for that. Because I have tried android studio can only read html file from folder assets.[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FUGY.png)

Comment: Android's `WebView` can't parse and run PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run PHP scripts you'll need PHP.
What you're doing here is loading a PHP file as a basic HTML one, so only the clientside is there and not the serverside where PHP should run the script and return the result to the client.

Comment: Can it work in offline mode? Is there any other way to run php script in offline mode in android. Please help me, I'm really confused